# Split column containing list of dics and match dictionnairy values to new column based on key

Tags: python, split

I am in need of some help in python.

I have a column in my dataset that contains a list of dictionaries. An example of the contents of such a cell are as follows:

```py
lyst = [
    {"region": "Baden-Wuerttemberg", "percentage":0.176553},
    {"region": "Bayern", "percentage":0.142457},
    {"region": "Bremen", "percentage":0.008874},
    {"region": "Hamburg", "percentage":0.01915},
    {"region": "Hessen", "percentage":0.09612},
    {"region": "Niedersachsen", "percentage":0.094816},
    {"region": "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "percentage":0.244745},
]
```

There are up to 17 dictionaries per list. Each list describes the percentage of ad targeting in each German states involved in an advertisement. Unfortunately the order in which the states are mentioned in each cell is different and some cells do not include some states that others do

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isNsT.png)

This is what the cells look like in the original dataset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVH8G.png)

Id like to split the column based on name of the region and then put the percentage value in the new cell. I have no idea where to start, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need an example of something which is like your data. Do not post all of you data, that would be overwhelming. However, no test data at all is also difficult to work with. Provide a simplified example of your data (not the whole thing, and not nothing at all). Also, never post code as an embeded .JPG. Instead, copy and paste the code into the question. Put three apostrophes at the beginning of your code, and three apostrophes at the end. This will cause stackoverflow.com to display your code in a mono-spaced font.

Comment: BTW there are 16 constituent [states in Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_of_Germany).

Answer (score 0):

We can generate some simple test data as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

cell1 = [
    {"region": "Baden-Wuerttemberg", "percentage":0.176553},
    {"region": "Bayern", "percentage":0.142457},
    {"region": "Bremen", "percentage":0.008874},
    {"region": "Hamburg", "percentage":0.01915},
    {"region": "Hessen", "percentage":0.09612},
    {"region": "Niedersachsen", "percentage":0.094816},
    {"region": "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "percentage":0.244745},
]

cell2 = [
    {'region': 'Baden-Wuerttemberg', 'percentage': 0.5882765},
    {'region': 'Bremen', 'percentage': 0.504437},
    {'region': 'Hessen', 'percentage': 0.54806}
]

old_data = pd.DataFrame({
        "Advert ID": ["Ad-" + str(id) for id in range(1, 3)],

        "Efficacy": [
            cell1,
            cell2
        ],
    }
)

print(old_data)
```

Now that we have some test data, we extract the names of the 17 German states.

```py
column = old_data["Efficacy"]
lysts = [t[1] for t in column.iteritems()]
regions = set(itts.chain.from_iterable([[d["region"] for d in lyst] for lyst in lysts]))
print(regions)
```

regions is a set of strings; something like the following:

```py
{'Nordrhein-Westfalen', 'Baden-Wuerttemberg', 'Bremen', 'Bayern', 'Niedersachsen', 'Hessen', 'Hamburg'}
```

let us make a new `pandas.DataFrame` such that there is one column for each of the German states.

```py
import pandas as pd

new_data = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = [old_data.columns[0]] + list(regions)
)
```

Now, you can populate the new data frame with data from the old data-frame.

## EDIT:

To populate the new-data frame with data from your old data-frame, you can write something like this:

```py
new_data = pd.DataFrame(
    columns = [old_data.columns[0]] + list(regions)
)

adverts = [t[1] for t in old_data["Advert ID"].iteritems()]
# print("adverts == ", repr(str(adverts))[1:-1])
for advert in adverts:
    old_row = old_data.loc[old_data["Advert ID"] == advert]
    list_of_dicts = old_row["Efficacy"].to_list()[0]
    rowi = 1 + len(new_data.index)
    new_data.at[rowi, "Advert ID"] = advert
    for dyct in list_of_dicts:
        region = dyct["region"]
        percentage = dyct["percentage"]
        new_data.at[rowi, region] = percentage
```

Let us display what we have:

```py
def pretty_print(df:pd.DataFrame):
    colw = 30 # column width is 40 characters wide
    import io
    strm = io.StringIO()
    d = df.to_dict()
    for key in d.keys():
        print( key.ljust(30), end="", file=strm)
        print(*[repr(str(v))[1:-1].ljust(colw) for v in d[key].values()], file=strm)
    # return strm.getvalue()
    print(strm.getvalue())

pretty_print(new_data)
```

We get something like:

```
Advert ID                     Ad-1                           Ad-2                          
Bremen                        0.008874                       0.504437                      
Baden-Wuerttemberg            0.176553                       0.5882765                     
Bayern                        0.142457                       nan                           
Hessen                        0.09612                        0.54806                       
Hamburg                       0.01915                        nan                           
Nordrhein-Westfalen           0.244745                       nan                           
Niedersachsen                 0.094816                       nan
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, many thanks for your answer, was very helpful & I learned something. I tried it out but am still having troubles at the step where you extract the 17 German states from the lists. "string indices must be integers" is the response I always get. I think that its not recognizing the list of dictionaries and is instead just reading it as a panda Series. Any ideas?